# Why is superscript not working properly in a table cell in Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive

The following screenshot is from a cell in a table in Google Docs. The "th" next to the 9 is supposedly in superscript, but is not actually ascending. It works normally if it's not in a table. Why might this happen and how can I fix it?

[image: A picture is worth a thousand words]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately they removed the option to edit html/css in the newest version so you can't really do much for that. Nice catch though. I think it's better to report that on their official Help Forum:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/label?lid=73938c871fa993cd&hl=en